# Black screen on instalation of Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

I am facing a big problem installing Ubuntu on my Gaming laptop ASUS ROG GL503V with graphics card NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1050 using an USB, I tried Ubuntu 18.04.4 AMD 64 and Ubuntu 19.10 AMD 64 that I downloaded from the official website, and none of them would work.

**Problems faced with 18.04.4 version:**

After I choose the option Install Ubuntu on GUI GRUB, it launches but goes into black screen immediately.

I solved this problem by not loading video drivers with adding `nomodeset` before quiet splash as its shows on the image below:

[image: Image grub]

but the screen becomes bigger, and this solution is permanent as it seems.

After the installation is finish and it wants to restart the laptop , it just doesn't load , it goes into a black screen again !!

**Problems faced with 19.10 version:**

After I click on install Ubuntu , and choose ether **install and remove all** option or **partition hard drive** option , the screen goes black on the start of the installation.

Answer (score 0):

At the blank screen, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>F4</kbd>  to be able to enter the Text-based user interface or start up your operating system in recovery mode.

Next step is trying to fix the problem. 
There may be files missing in the usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder: [re-installing x86_64-linux-gnu directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995467/re-installing-x86-64-linux-gnu-directory)